Linux mint doesn't boot after installing in old macbook 2007 white
After installing Linux mint with LVM in all disk space in macbook 2007, I installed this linux with guided installation, during installation i choosed erase disk and knstall, for advanced features i choosed LVM installation

Ifter installation completed I tried to restart the system for the first time and it cand boot ! Juste a gray screen and a directory climbing with interrogation mark

After booting with a Linux live I get this information about macbooc hdd
From gparted

From disk


Where is the problem !
There is a boot esp partition,  and lvm partition for filesystem

Please [edit] your question (don't add information in the comments) and describe what happens. How does it fail to boot? Any errors? Just a black screen? Some sort of login loop? How did you set Mint up? Do you see any boot options? The more detail you give, the more we will be able to help you.

I m returned to answer my question
I tryed to install linux mint x64 on a very old macbooc 2007 white, this hardware processor doesn't support x64 architecture
My porpuse is reviving a very old machine, After searching, I find some linux distributions that support x32 architrctur like AntiX linux and LMDE
So I refer to LMDE 6 site https://www.linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=308 to download x32 iso, I used BalenaEtcher to make a bootable USB, this USB formated already to GPT ; FAT32 format.
I booted to live LMDE to configure DISK, with gparted I made this configuration

a 2MiB partion without FS, flaged bios_grub
300MiB partition with FAT 32 flaged boot; esp
and other partitioning like mentioned in the previous image

Apple did not make any MacBooks in 2007 that did not have 64 bit processors. I believe BIOS booting is probably a better choice than EFI for your year Mac, but (assuming you have enough RAM) I would still have tried installing a 64 bit Linux.

Please don't post screenshots of console output. They are often difficult to read, the content will not show up in search engine results and cannot be automatically processed for vision-challenged persons. Instead, copy-and-paste the console output into your post using code formatting.

@David Anderson I tryed 3 distribution of linux x64, it didn'y boot ! but I m sur there is an option to boot x64 linux in old Mac

thank you for your advice @AdminBee

Can you post the output from the command cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name"? I want to make sure you have 64 bit processors.
